# Replace artifacts paths in TeamCity

Tags: maven, continuous-integration, teamcity

I have a multi-module maven project that is built by teamcity. This is working and the resulting artifacts are:

```
/core/target/core-system-1.2.3.war
/plugins/plugin-a/target/plugin-a-1.2.3.jar
/plugins/plugin-b/target/plugin-b-1.2.3.jar
/plugins/plugin-c/target/plugin-c-1.2.3.jar
/plugins/...
```

Currently, the artifacts are collected using this under general settings:

```
core/**/target/*.war => dist/core
plugins/**/target/*.jar => dist/plugins
```

So, I have all needed files in the `dist`-folder (afterwards they are pushed to a deployment-server via ssh). However, teamcity keeps the "target"-folder (which is also mentioned here [1]):

```
/dist/core/target/core-system-1.2.3.war
/dist/plugins/plugin-a/target/plugin-a-1.2.3.jar
/dist/plugins/plugin-b/target/plugin-b-1.2.3.jar
/dist/plugins/plugin-c/target/plugin-c-1.2.3.jar
```

What I need is to remove the `target` directory from the results:

```
/dist/core/core-system-1.2.3.war
/dist/plugins/plugin-a/plugin-a-1.2.3.jar
/dist/plugins/plugin-b/plugin-b-1.2.3.jar
/dist/plugins/plugin-c/plugin-c-1.2.3.jar
```

There are a lot of plugins and they change from time to time, so I don't want define them all with static paths. Therefore, using `plugins/plugin-a/target/*.jar => dist/plugins/plugin-a` is possible, but not feasible.

So, how can I remove the `target` directory from the artifact path, without selecting other jars that are not within the `target` directory?

[1] https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/Configuring+General+Settings#ConfiguringGeneralSettings-artifactPaths

TeamCity is 10.0.4

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried something like this:

```
core/**/target*/*.war => dist/core 
plugins/**/target*/*.jar => dist/plugins
```

According to TeamCity docs you referenced it's:

> [..] That is, TeamCity will create directories starting from the first occurrence of the wildcard in the pattern.

Comment: Tried that, but the result is the same. I expected that since the "first occurrence of the wildcard" is the `**` just before the target.